# Flat mapping observable properties in a observable collection in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Using RxSwift, say I have a class A that contains an observable of integer

```
class A: {
    let count: Observable<Int>
}
```

and a observable collection of objects of A

```
let data: Observable<[A]>
```

I want to define a `sum: Observable<Int>` that will be the sum of all the `count` on all the objects in `data`. Whenever the `data` observable collection changes or any of the `count` property changes the `sum` should also change.

How to achieve this? I tried some `flapMap` and `map` combinations but only got to a solution when `sum` gets updated only when `data` gets updated, ignoring the  `count` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```swift
let sum = data.flatMap { Observable.from($0).flatMap { $0.count }.reduce(0, accumulator: +) }
```

'.reduce()' emits only on completion, so it has to be inside of the outer '.flatMap()'

**Update 1:**

```swift
        let sumSubject: BehaviorSubject<Observable<Int>> = BehaviorSubject.create(Observable.empty())
        let sum = sumSubject.switchLatest()
        // every time it has to be a new 'data' observable!
        sumSubject.onNext(data.flatMap { Observable.from($0).flatMap { $0.count }.reduce(0, accumulator: +) })
```

**Update 2:**

```swift
    let counts: Observable<[Int]> = data.flatMap { Observable.combineLatest($0.map { $0.count }) }
    let sum: Observable<Int> = counts.map { $0.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } }
```

Comment: This just emits 0 for me. The version before edit emited the correct value firt time, but did not emit a new one when a `count` got updated.

Comment: Try adding '.debug()' after every operator to figure out where upstream of each operator completes. Basically, '.reduce()' emits only on completion of upstream, whereas '.scan()' on every upstream item. If everything else fails, try '.switchLatest()' on a 'BehaviourSubject<Observable<[A]>>' which you will feed with new 'Observable.just([A(), A(), ...])'

Comment: The problem with scan (in the version before edit) is that it will just keep adding the numbers when something changes, not counting it again. Like when a count changes from 1 to 2 the result will be not 2 but 3 (1+2).

Comment: Your solution results in `Observable<Int>` that emits the counts as they change, there is no good way to make a count from that. I guess getting to `Observable<[Int]>` somehow would be the goal.

Comment: Like 'data.flatMap { Observable.combineLatest($0.map { $0.count }) }' ? Good point.